# Finding path-lengths by the power of Adjacency matrix of an undirected graph

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix, nonnegative-matrices

I knew from Mark Newman's book - *Networks: An Introduction (Page 137, Eq: 6.31)*   that, if $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a graph, then $ij$'th entry of $A^k$ will give me the number of $k$-length paths connecting the vertices $i$ and $j$. This works very well for directed graphs. But does it work for undirected graphs too?

For instance, for the *undireceted* network below:
[image]

if i want to calculate how many $3$-length paths are there from vertex-$2$ to vertex-$1$, then I should find $[A^3]_{12}$. Proceeding in this way, I get, 
\begin{eqnarray}
A^3 = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
4 && 6 && 1 && 5 && 5 \\
6 && 2 && 3 && 6 && 2  \\
1 && 3 && 0 && 1 && 2 \\
5 && 6 && 1 && 4 && 5 \\
5 && 2 && 2 && 5 && 2
\end{matrix}
\right)
\end{eqnarray}
And, I find,

the *entry of the 1st row and 2nd column = 6 = entry of the 2nd row and 1st column*.

Does it mean that there are 6 paths of length 3 from vertex-2 to vertex-1? Cearly it is not true because I have only $1$ path of length $3$ from 2 to 1, namely the sequence: $(2,4,5,1)$.

What am I missing?

UPDATE:
I am attaching a snapshot of Newman's book. He only talks about "paths", but never about a "walk". Is it a mistake?

[Newman's book snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1b1i.jpg)

Comment: Walk is rather standard in modern graph theory ( Diestel)  and path means no edge repetition ( if loops are possible at some vertex then using a loop in the path repeat the vertex once)  . Yet at start of paragraph 6.10 Path: Newman mention that 'In general a path can intersect itself' so he uses it as a walk in standard sense.

Comment: While the existing answers clarified the terminology between path and walk, I am hoping for an answer for (actual) paths. Let's say I make a hack, I always reset the diagonal to zero after each power $A^k = A^{k-1} A$, $ \text{Diag}(A^k) := 0 $ to ban repeated vertices. Would it work?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The powers of the adjacency matrix don't give you the number of paths but the number of *walks* between any two vertices. In other words, you need to consider walks such that some vertices/edges are repeated (which do exist).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply, but I think, Newman's book says, it calculates the paths, not walks. I am still confused. :-/
I added a snapshot in the updated question.

Comment: How does your book define "path"?

Comment: Ahh, got it. They defined "*Hamiltonian Path*" as the path where a vertex cannot be visited more than once, and "*Eulerian path*" as the path where an edge cannot be visited more than once. I think, what you meant by "*walk*" is phrased simply as a "*path*" in that book. That clears the confusion. Thanks!

Comment: No problem; sometimes different books have subtle differences with regards to terminology, notation, and definitions, graph theory in particular.

Anyways, with that said, it's not too hard to see the 6 different walks (or paths as per your book) :
$(2, 4, 5, 1), (2, 1, 2, 1), (2, 1, 4, 1), (2, 1, 5, 1), (2, 4, 2, 1), (2, 5, 2, 1)$.

Comment: @benguin: Just to understand it completely: should your last mentioned path be (2,3,2,1) instead of (2,5,2,1)?

Comment: @maze_p: yes, correct

Answer (score 5):

You get the number of $k$ length walks. The difference between a path and a walk is that walks can repeat edges and vertices.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply, but I think, Newman's book says, it calculates the paths, not walks. I am still confused. :-/
I added a snapshot in the updated question.

Comment: Remark: Saying "repeating edges and vertices" is confusing it implicitly says that you could repeat a vertex without repaeating and edge on simple graphs without loops it is impossible.